# How do I install a non-PAE kernel on PAE-enabled hardware for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, pae

I need to install a non-PAE kernel for a 64-bit machine that supports PAE. 32-bit 12.04 currently comes with a PAE kernel but I need to get a non-PAE kernel. An older version of Ubuntu is also acceptable as long as it runs in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 32-bit 12.04 currently comes with a PAE kernel but I need to get a non-PAE kernel.

- It's as simple as doing this on your existing **32-bit** 12.04 installation:

  - `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic`
- followed by a this to remove the PAE kernel (so the system boots from the non-PAE by default):

  - `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic-pae`
  - Alternatively, comment out the `GRUB_HIDDEN` lines in `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub` to display the grub menu upon boot, from which you can select the kernel to use.
- **If you want to install a non-PAE kernel as part of a new installation**, start with Xubuntu or Lubuntu 12.04 32-bit, both of which come with the non-PAE kernel. Once running, you can run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to get the full Unity desktop experience.
- In general, the two common kernel suffixes for 12.04 are:

  1. `-generic` (non-PAE for 32-bit; standard for 64-bit)
  2. `-generic-pae` (PAE and default for 32-bit only)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't install non-pae kernel with this command (from previous answer):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-generic
```

But on output was a kernel version, in my case 3.2.0-27, so I modified the command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.2.0-27-generic
```

And it worked!

Comment: Sorry for the mistake -- please see edited answer. Just installing the metapackage `linux-image-generic` should be enough and will allow for seamless upgrading whenever new kernels of that variant are released.