# PAE on Core 2 duo CPU

Tags: xubuntu, non-pae

I have an Panasonic CF-52 with Core 2 duo P8400 CPU. I'm using Xubuntu 14.04. It has 4GB RAM. 
It's better to enable PAE for this system? 
Last time when I was using Elementary OS it was automatic downloading the PAE enable kernel, but Xubuntu does not.

Comment: it would be the best to use the [64bit-version](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/)...!

Comment: If Xubuntu 14.04 was installed new from Live media (means *not* upgraded from earlier release), the default kernel has PAE support. Related: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/150684/37165) was accepted for "How do I install a non-PAE kernel on PAE-enabled hardware for Ubuntu 12.04?", which also mentioned about Lubuntu/Xubuntu 12.04 and newer.

Comment: 14.04 32-bit comes with a PAE kernel but you'd be better off installing the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have over 4GB of RAM, then you don't need PAE. Ubuntu 12.04 and newer by default require PAE hardware.